# Copy images from iframe into textarea

Tags: javascript, image, iframe, copy

I would like to copy images from a iframe into a textarea. The pages and the iframe are not on the same domain or server.

**Any ideas on how to achieve this using javascript?**

The iframe with images is using ajax to collect images.

**Usage:**

For example I would like to use this method to copy images from a iframe into the tinymce text-editor of wordpress. Eg. display a iframe with a image gallery under the text-editor, and when they click on the image in the iframe the image should display in the text-editor (the image is alredy uploaded).

**Some ideas:**

Drag and drop the images seams to work in IE and FF.

Rightclick, copy and past images seams to work in IE and C.

It would be nice if I could get the src of the image in a variable, to be able to add "class" and "alt".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Copy images from iframe</title>
</head>

<body>

<textarea style="width:100%;height:400px" >I want to be able to get theme here like this
<img src="http://www.page.com/image.jpg" alt="">
</textarea>

<iframe width="100%" height="400px" src="http://www.page-with-images.com/"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"The pages and the iframe are not on the same domain or server."_ - So you can't do it. And from your comment under Purmou's answer you seem to already realise that you can't do it.

Comment: I tought there must be another way to exchange values between domains using javascript. If both domains accepted the exchange... Tough I CAN do it if I invlove PHP and file_get_contents().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Add a `click` event to `$("iframe img")`. In the `click` function, get the image's `src` and append that as an image tag to the tinyMCE editor.

This would look something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("iframe img").click(function(){
        var update = $("<div>").append(
            $("<img>").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"))
        ).html();

        $("#content").val(function( i, v ) {
            return v + update; 
        });
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/xEtL9/)..

We're pretty much cloning the image, placing it in a temporary `div`, getting the pure HTML content of the div (so that we convert the image object to a usable string), and updating the textarea's value with it. Of course, in the demo I linked, `#fake` is the equivalent of an `iframe` in this case.

Comment: The iframe is on another domain. Otherwise I might be able to do it :)

Comment: Then you can't do it. Period.

Comment: Maybe it can be done using localstorage? Just get the src in a varible som how :S

Comment: @Hakan - It would be kind of silly for browsers to implement a workaround for a security rule like this: wouldn't that make the rule kind of pointless?

Comment: @Hakan: You can use Flickr's API for example--load up some images in a page on your server and use that in the iframe.

Comment: Thanks Purmou. Thats a good idea. Also Picasa would be interesting. A free CDN for images. Tough, the problem is not getting the images to the iframe. It's getting them from the iframe into the content area...